# In Django Do CreateView and UpdateView have a default template name?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am following a YouTube tutorial and to the best of my knowledge the video creator did not specify a template name when he put PostUpdateView  and  PostCreateView in the URL patterns. Do both them views have a default template name as 'your model name'_form.html? Because I have a post_form.html template and I cannot see any URL pattern which is obviously referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, [as documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.template_name_suffix):

> `template_name_suffix`
>
> The `UpdateView` page displayed to a `GET` request uses a `template_name_suffix` of `_form`. For example, changing this attribute to `_update_form` for a view updating objects for the example `Author` model would cause the default `template_name` to be `myapp/author_update_form.html`.

A [similar pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.template_name_suffix) applies for `CreateView`.

Thus the default template will be `myapp/<model_name>_form.html` for both create and update views.